# How to extract a list of screaming snake case strings out of multiple files?

Tags: regex, shell, grep, find

I am searching for a way to extract "screaming snake case" strings from multiple files.

Screaming snake case is upper case words separated by underscore.
A regular expression would be `([A-Z]*_?[A-Z]*)*`.

Now I am searching for a way to find such matching strings in multiple files.
I expect grep or find could help?

What I have:

- multiple files in multiple sub directories
- shell possibilities of cygwin (so most common Linux commands are available)
- It could happen that multiple such strings are in one line

For example:

```
Some text WITH some SNAKE_CASE words.
```

The output should be a list like:

```
WITH
SNAKE_CASE
```

The use case for this is, that the snake case words are used as i18n keys for maintaining a properties file but there is no IDE support to keep all of them in sync.

What I am now using is:

```
find . -name "*.js" -exec grep -oP '\b[A-Z]+(_[A-Z]+)*\b' {} + | cut -d':' -f2 | sort | uniq
```

Thanks for support

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think you mean this,

```
grep -oP '\b[A-Z]+(_[A-Z]+)*\b' file
```

Just pass the above regex to find command.

```
find FOLDER -type f -exec grep -oP '\b[A-Z]+(_[A-Z]+)*\b' {} +
```

Comment: The regex looks good, you just need to `find FOLDER -type f -exec grep -oP '\b[A-Z](_[A-Z]+)*\b' {} +`

Comment: Yeah, without the `-P` you would not unnecessarily depend on GNU grep. But it would be `\w` instead of `\b` if you would use `grep -E`.. Also I would suggest to use `[[:upper:]]` instead of `[A-Z]` to make it work with different locales.

Comment: It will show only one upper case letter instead of the full snake case word.

Comment: I tried: `find . -type f -exec grep -oP '\w[[:upper:]](_[[:upper:]]+)*\w' {} +` but the output is of format: `filename:ySe` where ySe are three letters and obviously there is some lower case in it.

Comment: sorry, check mu ypdate